# Web interfaces for distribution rights to the Trac, SVN, proftpd

Tags: svn, interface, trac, rights

Are there any web interfaces for distribution rights to the trac, SVN, SFTP?

To the right of the listed services could easily edit the man who does not make friends with the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trac admin web-UI already supports permission groups and assigning allowed actions to both groups and individual users.

For setting more [fine grained permissions](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions) you'll want something like [FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin) (general), for repositories [TracSvnAuthzPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracSvnAuthzPlugin)  (simple) or [SvnAuthzAdminPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin) (advanced).

If do not use existing authentication infrastructure of your web-server you may want user/account administration inside Trac too. Look at [AccountManagerPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin). A common way is to let it manage a central file in htpasswd or htdigest format, that can be used by multiple services, even across several Trac environments, if you like.

Comment: Have a problems installing the plugin SvnAuthzAdminPlugin.

I run:
easy_install https://trac-hacks.org/svn/svnauthzadminplugin/0.12/

Plugin directory is created here:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin-0.2-py2.7.egg

resynchronization run, but I do not see SvnAuthzAdminPlugin of plugins list.

Comment: You need to explicitely enable plugin components, especially if installed globally. Easiest is to use the Trac plugins admin web-ui for that.

Answer (score 1):

trac.ini can be edit via webinterface with [TracIniAdminPanelPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracIniAdminPanelPlugin). I don't know webinterfaces for the other ones. I think it's because there are so many ways to setup the authorization configurations.